# NativeActivity spawn standard Activity problems

Tags: android, native-activity

I have a NativeActivity app that i ideally want to display a standard GUI layout over the top of at one point.  Ive looked around alot and tried various things that people have suggested but cant seem to get anything to work.

The main reponse ive found seems to be the way to do this is to create a new Intent and start a new class extended from Activity.  In this new class use setContentView(...) to set the layout to use.

I have got this new activity starting and it does indeed call the setContentView however i seem to have a pure black screen

I guess the questions are:

1. Is this the best way to put a GUI over the top of nativeactivity
2. Is this even possible
3. Am I missing something obvious

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In various video players they usually put a semitransparent activity with various UI controls over a fullscreen activity which plays the video. That fullscreen activity can as well be native.